# RAM allocated in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox and also want to run it, but when I want to create kali Linux max based ram memory allocated it only 6GB, how do I change it?. can it change to higher more than 6GB? I watch it can reach higher than mine. my computer have 8gb ram. I need your help. I put my virtual box screenshot to
[image: screenshot][image: screenshot2][image: screenshot3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy to do.

```
Power down the VM (the guest has to be off, not just not running but with a saved state).
Discard 'Saved State'
Open the VM's settings.
Open the System tab.
Change the "Base memory" value to however much RAM you want.
```

Comment: i don't find system tab. where is it?

Comment: when you click on the 'gear' icon another screen with several vertical tabs should open. The second one is called 'system'.

Comment: how to power down VM?

Comment: shut down the system like you normally would.

Comment: in my preference doesn't have 'system'

Comment: It's not under 'preference' but in the 'Settings' section. Also, do you really need more than 6GB RAM for a VM in a 8GB system? If your host OS runs with too little resources nothing will run smoothly.

Comment: in VM setting i don't see  change "based memory" tab

Comment: can we discuss in chat, and you guide me to change it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230205/discussion-between-captcha-and-ryand).

Comment: Issue resolved. OP wanted to assign too much RAM, leaving host with too few resources. Vbox protection kicked in and didn't allow them to even save the config. Confusing at first but worked it out through chat.

Answer (score 0):

1. Power off the virtual box
2. Go to settings and click system allocate memory and click ok

Memory is changed successfully!